# How to manage multilabel segmentation map for Active contour loss?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am using Active contour loss (https://github.com/xuuuuuuchen/Active-Contour-Loss/blob/master/Active-Contour-Loss.py) which is as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
def Active_Contour_Loss(y_true, y_pred): 

#y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, dtype = 'float64')


x = y_pred[:,:,1:,:] - y_pred[:,:,:-1,:] # horizontal and vertical directions 
y = y_pred[:,:,:,1:] - y_pred[:,:,:,:-1]

delta_x = x[:,:,1:,:-2]**2
delta_y = y[:,:,:-2,1:]**2
delta_u = K.abs(delta_x + delta_y) 

epsilon = 0.00000001 # where is a parameter to avoid square root is zero in practice.
w = 1
lenth = w * K.sum(K.sqrt(delta_u + epsilon)) # equ.(11) in the paper

"""
region term
"""

C_1 = np.ones((256, 256))
C_2 = np.zeros((256, 256))

region_in = K.abs(K.sum( y_pred[:,0,:,:] * ((y_true[:,0,:,:] - C_1)**2) ) ) # equ.(12) in the paper
region_out = K.abs(K.sum( (1-y_pred[:,0,:,:]) * ((y_true[:,0,:,:] - C_2)**2) )) # equ.(12) in the paper

lambdaP = 1 # lambda parameter could be various.

loss =  lenth + lambdaP * (region_in + region_out) 

return loss
```

However, when I use it for the U-net model. I am getting below error while compiling.

```
    InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1606   try:
-> 1607     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1608   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 256 for 'loss_2/activation_57_loss/mul_1' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,256,4], [?,256,256].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
12 frames
<ipython-input-33-b98b233ef3b2> in <module>()
     50 # model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     51 
---> 52 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=Active_Contour_Loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    343                 with K.name_scope(self.output_names[i] + '_loss'):
    344                     output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
--> 345                                                 sample_weight, mask)
    346                 if len(self.outputs) > 1:
    347                     self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    426         """
    427         # score_array has ndim >= 2
--> 428         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
    429         if mask is not None:
    430             # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in Theano

<ipython-input-32-b273672af934> in Active_Contour_Loss(y_true, y_pred)
     28         C_2 = np.zeros((256, 256))
     29 
---> 30         region_in = K.abs(K.sum( y_pred[:,0,:,:] * ((y_true[:,0,:,:] - C_1)**2) ) ) # equ.(12) in the paper
     31         region_out = K.abs(K.sum( (1-y_pred[:,0,:,:]) * ((y_true[:,0,:,:] - C_2)**2) )) # equ.(12) in the paper
     32 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    897     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    898       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 899         return func(x, y, name=name)
    900       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    901         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in _mul_dispatch(x, y, name)
   1204   is_tensor_y = isinstance(y, ops.Tensor)
   1205   if is_tensor_y:
-> 1206     return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)
   1207   else:
   1208     assert isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)  # Case: Dense * Sparse.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in mul(x, y, name)
   6699   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   6700   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 6701         "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
   6702   _result = _op.outputs[:]
   6703   _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    792         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None, name=scope,
    793                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 794                          op_def=op_def)
    795 
    796       # Conditionally invoke tfdbg v2's op callback(s).

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in create_op(***failed resolving arguments***)
   3355         raise TypeError("Input #%d is not a tensor: %s" % (idx, a))
   3356     return self._create_op_internal(op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name,
-> 3357                                     attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3358 
   3359   def _create_op_internal(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3424           input_types=input_types,
   3425           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3426           op_def=op_def)
   3427       self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_device=compute_device)
   3428     return ret

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1768           op_def, inputs, node_def.attr)
   1769       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
-> 1770                                 control_input_ops)
   1771     # pylint: enable=protected-access
   1772 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1608   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1609     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1610     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1611 
   1612   return c_op

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 256 for 'loss_2/activation_57_loss/mul_1' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,256,4], [?,256,256].
```

I tried to assign C_1 and C_2 with shape (256,256,4). But, the segmentation mask is not generated. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The source code you shared for Active Contours seems fine. Probably, you are feeding the loss function with wrong parameter size.

Since the code is working with tensors, you should feed the function 4-D. Try something like that:

```
a0 = np.zeros([1,256,256,1], dtype='float64')
a0[0,...] = np.expand_dims(C_1, -1).astype(np.float64)
a1 = np.zeros([1,256,256,1], dtype='float64')
a1[0,...] = np.expand_dims(C_2, -1).astype(np.float64)
los_ac = Active_Contour_Loss(a0, a1)
print(sess.run(los_ac))
```

I wrote this code quickly but I suppose it'll work.